# Method as inline function in ASP.Net

Tags: html, attributes, inline

I have a method, that returns a resource value based on a given file name and label.

This works fine in between HTML tags, but I cannot seem to get this to work with attributes.

This question has been asked so many times, but mostly on property values, not a method that returns data.

Given the following method:

GetGlobalResourceObject("Introduction", "ButtonStates")

It returns, from the Introduction.[culture].resx the current translation for ButtonStates label. In the following context it works:

```
<div class="ButtonLabel">
   <label>
      <%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Introduction", "ButtonStates")%>
   </label>
</div>
```

How do I get this method working within an attribute?

```
<div class="ButtonLabel" data-label="<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Introduction", "ButtonStates")%>">
```

I have tried all the varients I could find on the net, none of them work for a method:

```
<div class="ButtonLabel" data-label='&lt;%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Introduction", "ButtonStates")%&gt;'>

<div class="ButtonLabel" data-label="<%$PartialPage:GetGlobalResourceObject("Introduction", "ButtonStates")%>">
```

as examples.

Answer (score 1):

try to use it like this

```
<div class="ButtonLabel" data-label="<%=Resources.Introduction.ButtonStates %>">
```

this will work fine if the element is html not asp.net element

but if you want to use it inline in asp control like button  use like this

```
<input runat="server" id=txt placeholder="<%$Resources:Introduction,ButtonStates %>" />
```

this the way I used and it 's work I hope

Comment: Ofcourse. Stupid me. Thanks Muhammad, feel like nut now :$